# Blender Grid axis colors

Tags: customization

Does anyone know how to change the X and Y axis color in Blender 2.80?

[image: How do I change the grid axis color in blender 2.80?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the axis colors in the following settings tab:

**Preferences -> Themes -> User Interface -> Axis and Gizmo colors**

[image]

Happy Blending! :)